# Is sourcing a file already sourced in the parent script optional?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

If i have a file that contains a function `foo` and I have the following flow:
Script A `sources` the file that has `foo` and calls `foo`.
Then script A executes another script file that also calls `foo`. That second script also sources the same file.
I was wondering is there a way to conditionally source the file in the second script or there is no impact and this approach is usual?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: [linux how does source work](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+how+does+source+work+site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

If script A executes something else, then that program doesn't inherit the function definitions. Bash has an obscure feature to export functions through the environment. This was mostly unknown until there was a vulnerability in the implementation. If you really want, you can export functions with `export -f`, but it's better to just define the functions you want to use instead of relying on those functions being present in the environment.

Comment: I am fine with the approach if it is normal. I am asking only to understand if that is the way to do things

Answer (score 0):

As RalfFriedl already explained, whether or not this can have some impact, depends what is actually executed inside the sourced script. Since you didn't tell us the content of that script, there is no way that we can say whether this has impact or not.

In any case, I would consider it bad design to do this type of checking in the second scripts. Sourced scripts should be written in a way, that they are idempotent - I should be allowed to source the script as often as I like, without experiencing any penalty.

There are few things which we want to "happen only once". A typical case is appending something to, i.e. `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If we source the script several times, the path would get longer and longer. If we want to avoid this, the protection should go into the sourced script, not in the sourcing one. A pattern which I often use, goes like this:

```
# Put /foo/bar on top of PATH
: ${_src_xyz_version:=1}
if [[ ${_SRC_XYZ:=0} != $_src_xyz_version ]]
then
  export _SRC_XYZ=$_src_xyz_version
  export PATH=/foo/bar:$PATH
fi
```

In this case, once the PATH has been extended, running the script again in my process or any sub-process does not modify the PATH again, **unless** a process explicitly changes requests it by doing a

```
export _SRC_XYZ=0
```